# Prisma, select row from table 1, depending on the latest foreign key in table 2

Tags: prisma

Apologies for the bad title, struggling to think of another.

Currently, I have 2 tables, `publication` and `publicationStatus`.

A publication will looking something like:

```json
{
    "id": "ckyil950d00027v2str5ljo7h",
    "url_slug": "ckyil950e00037v2s4mqxvaho",
    "type": "PEER_REVIEW",
    "title": "Intersting review",
    "content": "Content is optional at this stage",
    "doi": "1093/ajae/aaq063",
    "createdBy": "test-user-1",
    "createdAt": "2022-01-17T11:12:50.845Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-01-17T11:12:50.847Z",
    "publicationStatus": [
        {
            "status": "LIVE",
            "createdAt": "2022-01-19T11:12:50.846Z",
            "id": "ckyil950e00047v2sx4urbfte"
        },
        {
            "status": "DRAFT",
            "createdAt": "2022-01-17T11:12:50.846Z",
            "id": "ckyil950e00047v2sx4urbfth"
        }
    ],
    "user": {
        "id": "test-user-1",
        "firstName": "Test",
        "lastName": "User 1"
    }
}
```

Where `publication` has a 1 to many relationship with `publicationStatus`.

What I need to do is a `find` query where it only returns a `publication` if the **latest** `publicationStatus` for that `publication`, has a `status` of `LIVE`.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
The closest I could come to is this **psuedo** code:

```js
await prisma.publication.findFirst({
    where: {
        id,
        publicationStatus: {
            where: {
                status: 'LIVE'
            },
            take: 1,
            orderBy: {
                createdAt: 'desc'
            }
        },
    }
});
```

This code does **not** work, but demonstrates a picture of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I see that the `where` condition has the publication's `id` field. Does that mean you're querying a _single_ publication, by its `id`? In addition, what is your desired returned data in case the latest `publicationStatus` is not `LIVE`?

Comment: So if the `publicationStatus` is not `LIVE`, a `null` is fine. Right now it's for a single `id`, the API would return `null` or the object. However, will need something similar for my `GET /publications` where it will return all (with pagination) for publications that are `LIVE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to do what you're hoping directly with a Prisma Query at the moment. I can suggest two possible workarounds though:

**Approach 1:** Fetch the most recent `publicationStatus` along with the `publication` and check the `status` inside your node application.

This is what the query would look like:

```js
    let publication = await prisma.publication.findFirst({
        where: {
            id
        },
        include: {
            publicationStatus: {
                orderBy: {
                    createdAt: 'desc'
                },
                take: 1
            }
        }
    });

    // check publication.publicationStatus[0].status and handle appropriately
```

**Approach 2:** Write a raw SQL query using the [`queryRaw`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#queryraw) method.

For a single publication, I think it would be easier to use approach 1. However, if you want to return *all* LIVE publications (you mentioned this in a comment), the performance characteristics of approach 1 might be undesirable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. We decided to take an even simpler approach and add a `currentStatus` field to `publications`, that should update whenever the `publicationStatus` one is.

Comment: Great, glad to see you found a suitable workaround :D